# Calling a Jasper Studio report from Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Jaspersoft advertises the ability to "embed" reports into your *Java* application.  I think I'm missing some fundamental step...

I can create reports through a JDBC connection to *MySQL*.  It runs fine.  It generates the *.jrxml* file, but then what?  How do I call this report from Java?  (I use *Netbeans*).  Are there JasperReports libraries I need to import?  Or do I have to also install the report server? I was hoping to write a report, embed it into the code, and be able to run that off any computer (not just one that has the report server installed).  Is that possible?  How do I call the report and pass in the parameters?  Something like

```
JasperReport jr = new JasperReport(param1, param2)
```

Something along those lines?  Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("path/filename.jrxml");

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("parameter_name", value); //only if you want to pass any parameters

JRDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource(); //your db connection

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
```

Now you have a JasperPrint which you can export, show and print.

You can also refer to [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) for more details.